# BASH script - Why am I getting a syntax error?

Tags: sql, postgresql, bash

**Why am I getting a syntax error when I try to add the winner_id and the opponent_id?**

I'm stuck on a FreeCodeCamp project and would appreciate any help!

I have to create a Bash script that enters information from World Cup games into PostgreSQL.

**Here's the first few rows from games.csv**

```
year,round,winner,opponent,winner_goals,opponent_goals
2018,Final,France,Croatia,4,2
2018,Third Place,Belgium,England,2,0
2018,Semi-Final,Croatia,England,2,1
2018,Semi-Final,France,Belgium,1,0
2018,Quarter-Final,Croatia,Russia,3,2
2018,Quarter-Final,England,Sweden,2,0
```

**Here’s my insert_data.sh**

```
if [[ $1 == "test" ]]
then
  PSQL="psql --username=postgres --dbname=worldcuptest -t --no-align -c"
else
  PSQL="psql --username=freecodecamp --dbname=worldcup -t --no-align -c"
fi

# Do not change code above this line. Use the PSQL variable above to query your database.

echo $($PSQL "TRUNCATE TABLE games, teams")

cat games.csv | while IFS="," read YEAR ROUND WINNER OPPONENT WG OG
do

  if [[ $WINNER != "winner" ]]
  then 
  WINNER_ID=$($PSQL "SELECT team_id FROM teams WHERE name LIKE '$WINNER'")
      
    if [[ -z $WINNER_ID ]]
    then
    RESULT_INSERT_WINNER=$($PSQL "INSERT INTO teams (name) VALUES ('$WINNER')")
    fi

  fi        

  if [[ $OPPONENT != "opponent" ]]
  then 
  OPPONENT_ID=$($PSQL "SELECT team_id FROM teams WHERE name LIKE '$OPPONENT'")
      
    if [[ -z $OPPONENT_ID ]]
    then
    RESULT_INSERT_OPPONENT=$($PSQL "INSERT INTO teams (name) VALUES ('$OPPONENT')")
    fi
    
  fi

  if [[ $YEAR != "year" ]]
  then
    ADD_DATA=$($PSQL "INSERT INTO games(year, round, winner_id, opponent_id, winner_goals, opponent_goals) VALUES($YEAR, '$ROUND', $WINNER_ID, $OPPONENT_ID, $WG, $OG)")
  fi
done
```

**Here’s the error I’m getting in the Bash terminal**

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ...inner_goals, opponent_goals) VALUES(2018, 'Final', , , 4, 2)
                                                              ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ...goals, opponent_goals) VALUES(2018, 'Third Place', , , 2, 0)
```

There's more of the same.

Comment: This does not look like an error issued by bash, but by psql. I suggest that you post here the exact SQL statement as it is executed (i.e. after variable expansion). The easiest way to optain this, is to turn on tracing (with `set -x`) in your script.

Comment: Where should $WINNER_ID and $OPPONENT_ID come from? These are empty when you INSERT a new team. Use RETURNING to get the id.

Comment: What is not clear in this error message: `VALUES(2018, 'Final', , , 4, 2)`? There's no any values between commas, you have to debug `$WINNER_ID` etc composition

Comment: The error message is very clear: `VALUES (2018, 'Final', , , 4, 2)` is syntactically incorrect SQL.

Comment: According to the overall logic: the above script has a lot of interaction between a shell and a database, which leads to a lot of effort to support. Generate a single pl/pgsql block that encapsulates all the logic and accepts input parameters. It will be **much** easier to debug in SQL console and then pass parameters to it

Comment: Also please note that in Postgres you may use `insert` as a row source (using `returning`), so you may put it in the `with` clause and then process the value in the downstream subqueries. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0C3BF7kC)

Comment: You should not be using `bash` to construct dynamic SQL queries like this. Choose a language with a proper SQL library to construct the queries safely.

Comment: A hopefully useful aside - https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-assign the winner_id and opponent_id after inserting into the teams table with the new_id at the end.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).